# one generic class create generic extension with expression<T,bool> method

Tags: c#, generics, methods, expression

My code is as follows:

```
public partial class WhereHelper<T1> { }
public static partial class WhereHelperExtension
{
    public static T Where<T,T1>(this T t, Expression<Func<T1,bool>> where) where T : WhereHelper<T1>
    {
        //do something....
        return t;
    }
}
public class Test
{
    public void Main()
    {
        WhereHelper<DateTime> dt = new WhereHelper<DateTime>();
        dt.Where(t => t.Year == 2016);//this is error
        dt.Where<WhereHelper<DateTime>, DateTime>(t => t.Year == 2016);//this is success
    }
}
```

Extension method I want to be like this：

```
WhereHelper<DateTime> dt = new WhereHelper<DateTime>();
dt.Where(t => t.Year == 2016);//this is error
```

how to  create generic extension with Expression  method.
Visual Studio does not recognize the "Where" extension methods.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Visual Studio does not recognize the "Where" extension methods.

Comment: From the code shown it's not clear to me what this extension should actually do and what _type_ it should extend. You `return t;` meaning you return the instance you actually want to extend? Please edit your question and explain what you are trying to achieve. What does `Where` on a single `DateTime` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, if you need to provide *any* generic argument, you must provide them all. `where` constraints do not provide hints to the type resolver, and so it's impossible to decide what `T1` is.

Change your signature to the following:

```
public static WhereHelper<T> Where<T>(this WhereHelper<T> t, Expression<Func<T,bool>> where)
{
    return t;
}
```

Here, we know *exactly* what `T`, purely from the first argument, and so we do not have to explicitly specific the arguments.

Comment: I do not want this result, The WhereHelper<T> has derived classes.

Comment: The explanations are quite correct, but what is an extension that returns the extended instance immediatly good for?

Comment: @ZhiJunLin The above code provides identical functionality. You can still use a derived class with the above.

Comment: @RenéVogt Not sure - I'm guessing it's just a placeholder until it compiles (and will eventually be written in a fluent-style)